# Directx9 Reset Device

Tags: directx, directx-9

I have a problem when resetting device after the state was lost. I can reset the Direct3D device but when i call OnLostDevice function on ID3DXFont i get an error.

```
First-chance exception at 0x00e6ec05 in Turbo3D.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.
Unhandled exception at 0x76ee15de in Turbo3D.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.
```

When i keep a break point at

```
Font->OnLostDevice();
```

I can see that the Font is referring to a memory address 0xcccccccc which is not accessible.

Any Idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Did you ensured, that `Font` isn't freed before? It seems that the pointer isn't valid anymore. You should add some more code, which show the assignments and usage of `Font`.

Comment: Yeah I'm very sure that i'm not releasing the pointer, My code is very heavy I shall add it in pastebin and give u a link.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tBERJVML

Comment: I found it. Its because I forgot that i was inheriting this class.  I have created a new object and tried to access that. ;) Thanks